# Issues with excel file. XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: What kind of file is this?

Tags: python, macos, excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I have a bit of code that works with an xls file. It works for everything I've thrown at it except this one file and I don't know how to properly identify what this one file is. I get the file off of a website I am navigating with Selenium. This particular spreadsheet always downloads as a file type that causes this error.

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Meir/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/code/ifg_TPA_update_excel.py", line 44, in <module>
    rb = open_workbook((os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/Selenium test/TPA_Example.xls")),formatting_info=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 443, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 94, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1262, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1256, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\xff\xfe<\x00S\x00T\x00'
```

The file I am trying to open displays as an xls file in my finder. However, when I open it, it does not open with the file name as the header but rather displays "Workbook1". When I hit save, it opens the save menu as if I had clicked save as, and defaults to "Workbook1.xlsx". I tried changing my code to open it as an xlsx file, but then it errors out saying it cannot find the file. Whenever I try googling it, I don't know how to phrase it to get a relevant answer.

When I contacted the websites support team asking what kind of file the TPA bulks op sheet is they replied:

> The TPA bulk ops is an older version than the rest of the bulk ops, it's due to be rebuilt some time later this year.  When downloading the file your best bet is to do a Save As and save it as an older version of .xls, I usually select Microsoft Excel 5.0/95 Workbook, and also format it as text.  Formatted that way it should upload without issue.

Any ideas as to how I can open this right from Python?

Currently I am building each part as a separate code and I was going to combine them all together once I get it sorted out. The below is the section of code that will be opening the file and is experiencing the error.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
## Import OS and Modules
import os
import csv
import xlrd
import xlwt
import xlutils
import csv
import collections

## Define Input File from IFG
ifg_user_file = "New_PCs_to_set_up_in_marketing_database_-_4-11-2013.csv"

## Import data
data = [row for row in csv.reader(open (os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/" + ifg_user_file),'U'))]

## Find number of rows
row_count = sum(1 for row in data)
print row_count
## Set to turn off when reaching the end of data
end_of_data = False

from xlutils.copy import copy # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils
from xlrd import open_workbook # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
from xlwt import easyxf # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

##################################################################################
## THE ERROR OCCURS AT THE LINE BELOW 
rb = open_workbook((os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/Selenium test/TPA_Example.xls")),formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) # read only copy to introspect the file
```

**EDIT: I tried to open it with codecs rather than open for diagnostics**

```
rb=codecs.open((os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/Selenium test/TPA_Example.xls")), 'r', encoding='utf16');
print rb;
print rb.readline();
print rb.read(20);
```

It printed the following result:

```
<open file '/Users/Meir/Documents/PYTHON/Selenium test/TPA_Example.xls', mode 'rb' at 0x110fe51e0>
<STYLE>

            .excel { BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px so
```

It looks like it is an excel document then. Not sure how to proceed. **Is there a universal open an excel document command?**

Comment: You have UTF-16 data there, perhaps it's a CSV or XML file? First three characters: `<ST`. That does not look like `XLS` or `XLSX` to me..

Comment: Well the first file I open is a csv. The second file I open may possibly have some xml characteristics left in it though it says xls. I did not see the "<ST" anywhere. Can you point out where it indicated the UTF-16? I tried to change the extension to xls and csv, but when I opened in xcode, they displayed as a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: The error message: `Expected BOF record; found '\xff\xfe<\x00S\x00T\x00'`. Those bytes are the UTF-16 BOM followed by 3 UTF-16 bytes representing `<ST`. You could open the wile with `codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf16')` and do some reads on that  to see what kind of data you find.

Comment: So that worked and it opens now, but I error out on my next line. '''AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_index' '''. Can you clarify on what I would do to test it. Sorry, I am very inexperienced with encoding. Also, do you happen to know how I can open it as a spreadsheet still? Thank you very much by the way.

Comment: No, that was not meant as a solution. It was meant as a means for you to introspect what is in the file, so you can figure out what format it *is* in. It is **not** a XLS file.

Comment: I got that part. If there is no way to open it as an excel file, how would I use it being open to see what kind of file it is? Would I just try a bunch of functions that would only work on a specific file type and whichever one works is the file type in question? Or is there a more direct method?

Comment: You open it in a python interpreter using `import codecs; f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf16')`, then calling `f.read(100)` or `f.readline()` and see what is returned from those calls.

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you with all this. It appears to have opened as an excel file. At least that is what I assume from the extension on the bottom line of the result. The line appears to be cut off, but that is all that came up.

Comment: No, that is an HTML file representing the contents of the original Excel spreadsheet, *at best*.